# vba sheet color range Format

Tags: vba, excel

Hi everyone I have 40 tabs in a spreadsheet when I copy grouped sheets the color changes,

I have written a code only to update the affected sheets but its not working, any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Color()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim rngs As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If ws.Name <> "A" And ws.Name <> "B" And ws.Name <> "C" And _
       ws.Name <> "D" And ws.Name <> "E" And ws.Name <> "F" Then    
        Set r1 = Range("B1:E3")
        Set r2 = Range("N1:P3")

        Set rngs = Union(r1, r2)

        With rngs.Interior
           .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           .Color = 49407
           .TintAndShade = 0
           .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next ws    

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: use `Select Case ws.Name` and then `Case "A","B","C","D","E","F"` , and under the `Case Else` write this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try qualifying the ranges with the sheet by changing this:

```
Set r1 = Range("B1:E3")
Set r2 = Range("N1:P3")
```

to:

```
Set r1 = ws.Range("B1:E3")
Set r2 = ws.Range("N1:P3")
```